# Javascript function calling form element is not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, forms

```
  function HandleFileButtonClick(val)
  {
      var ss=val.name;
      var n=ss.split("choiceimgs");
      alert(n[1]);
      document.forms["addpoll"]["choiceimg" + n[1]].click();
  }
```

In the above coding it holds the variable value upto n[1]. The alert shows a number. If the line works then it will click a file input and the browser window will open.

This works fine in chrome, but in IE8 is not working. How to write the above line in IE8. And also `document.forms['addpoll']['choiceimg'+i].style.display='';`

this line also not working in my page. I tried the whole day to fix this. But I can't find any solution. Anyone can help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide a full example at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: sure. I will paste the code in jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry that is also not working in Js fiddle. That is I cant reduce the coding and paste it in jsfiddle. Very sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because no examples are available I **assume** that the code line

```
document.forms["addpoll"]["choiceimg" + n[1]].click();
```

points to a form field. If so then you have to change it into follows:

```
document.forms["addpoll"].elements["choiceimg" + n[1]].click();
```

I am not sure to 100 perscent that the concatenation of `.click()` is correct, though the change to

```
document.forms['addpoll'].elements['choiceimg'+i].style.display='';
```

By the way I recommend the explicit use of value `none` and `display`, so you can exclude a source of error.